# to write a function that tests whether a Point is in a Rectangle

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, floating-point

the question is as follows:

write and test a program with the following features.

Firstly, defines a new structured type called Point, is represented with floats for the x and y values

. Also, define a new structured type called Rectangle, which has sides parallel to the x-axis and yaxis, allowing you to represent the rectangle with the bottom_left and top_right Points.

Next write a function that computes and returns the area of a Rectangle, based upon the Rectangle parameter passed into the function.

Avoid pass by value, ensure the function exhibits pass by reference behaviour

Ensure the function returns the appropriate type of data

Next write a function that tests whether a Point is in a Rectangle. This function should take in two parameters by reference, the Point and the Rectangle to test. The function must return an integer value of one if the point is inside the rectangle, otherwise it should return zero. Write a main function, with appropriate local variables as test data to then use on the two functions above

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 struct Point
 {
     float x;
     float y;
 };

 struct Rectangle
 {
     struct Point lb;    // left below point
     struct Point ru;    // right upper point
 };

 float getArea(struct Rectangle r)
 {
     return (r.ru.x - r.lb.x)*(r.ru.y - r.lb.y);
 }

 void setValue(struct Point* p, float x, float y)
 {
     p->x = x;
    p->y = y;
 }

 void setValueP(struct Rectangle* r, struct Point* lb, struct Point* ru)
 {
    r->lb = *lb;
     r->ru = *ru;
 }

 void setValueR(struct Rectangle* r, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
 {
     r->lb.x = x1;
     r->lb.y = y1;
     r->ru.x = x2;
     r->ru.y = y2;
 }

 int contains(struct Rectangle r, struct Point p)
 {
     if((p.x > r.lb.x && p.x && p.x < r.ru.x) && (p.y > r.lb.y && p.y && p.y < r.ru.y))
        return 1;
     return 0;
 }

 int main()
 {
     struct Rectangle r;
    setValueR(&r, 1, 2, 6, 8);

     printf("%f\n", getArea(r));

     struct Point p1;
    setValue(&p1, 4, 5);
     struct Point p2;
     setValue(&p2, 4, 1);

     if(contains(r, p1))
         printf("inside the Rectangle\n");
     else
         printf("outside the Rectangle\n"); 

     if(contains(r, p2))
         printf("inside the Rectangle\n");
     else
         printf("outside the Rectangle\n"); 
 }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: This not the place where you get your home work done. Put your effort to find the solution first. If you couldn't, post your observations. And be more specific when you ask questions.

Comment: @Mohammad.L Please don't take my comments in a negetive sense. I just added it to encourage you to put some more research effort. That's all. :)

Comment: Your code is C++ code, not C code! It will output on a C++ compiler "30.000000
inside the Rectangle
outside the Rectangle"

Comment: @Constantin i need it to be a c programming code, could you please help me?

Comment: @sreeyesh sorry sir i am under a lot of pressure, as this is one of the first few times i am working with stuff like this, and this question has got me dumbfounded so all i could do is post it online

Comment: @sreeyesh could you suggest me some good reading and practice resourses aswell?

Comment: @Mohammad.L I don't use such words with other people. You have shown your culture. I don't accept something from strangers. Keep it with you. :)

Comment: @Mohammad.L I had worked as a teacher for a few years. This is the way I used to teach my students. I didn't mean to hurt your feelings.

Comment: When editing the question, do not change the original posted code as that makes many of the comments irrelevant.   Instead, add a a new code segment and/or new question segment.   BTW: the new code looks correct. (I have not tested it)

Comment: Note: the code seems to assume that x=0, y=0 is in the bottom left corner.   On most displays, 0,0 is in the upper left corner

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you compile c++, those errors look like c++ code compiling with c compiler

Answer (score 0):

> i need it to be a c programming code, could you please help me?

The C language does not have 'reference' parameters and does not have 'classes' and does not have the concept of 'this'.

The code needs to be changed to not use references not classes nor 'this'.

You could start with changing:

```
struct Point
{
    float x;
    float y;
    Point(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y)
{}
Point()
{}
};
```

to this:

```
struct Point
{
    float x;
    float y;
};
```

Then, need to include the 'struct' modifier when referencing 'Point' as there is no 'Point' class but there is a 'Point' struct.

So change this:

```
struct Rectangle
{
    Point lb;       //  left below point
    Point ru;       //  right upper point
    ...
```

to this:

```
struct Rectangle
{
    struct Point lb;       //  left below point
    struct Point ru;       //  right upper point
};
```

The setValue() function is using references for the parameters and using the C++ 'this' to indicate the current object:

```
void setValue(Point& lb, Point& ru)
{
    this->lb = lb;
    this->ru = ru;
}
```

However, C does not have the 'this' nor 'references'. To write it for C, use:

```
void setValue( struct rectangle *pRect, struct Point *pLB, struct Point *pRU)
{
    pRect->lb.x = pLB->x;
    pRect->lb.y = pLB->y;
    pRect->ru.x = pRU->x;
    pRect->ru.y = pRU->y;
} // end function: setValue
```

similar considerations pertain for the rest of the posted code.